# Is it possible to use a (not running) laptop as a second monitor?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I'd just like to use an old laptop (that still works, but that should not be turned on) as a second screen via hdmi. (the old laptop used to be rather powerful and will still eat way too much energy and having the ventilation run all the time isn't fun either, so all other solutions I found here do not really work for me, since the software based solutions tend to require both machines to be running)

It feels like the screen is still there, so it should be usable as just a screen, but maybe the way it is connected to the computer part of the laptop makes this impossible?

Comment: ...In short, no. 1. HDMI is a one-way communication. 2. Nothing works without power. A laptop that's switched off is a door-stop as regards functionality.

Comment: Indeed, the connection makes it impossible for people that need to ask about it. It's possible for someone with the required skills set and additional hardware. Considering that the screen would need to be removed from the laptop and connected to an external circuit board with the electronics required to add an HDMI port and power input, flapping on the breeze, something not available at Amazon or stores, fit some sort of support to have it stand in an usable position, ... No, not practical and expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your laptop's HDMI is output only.

You can on the other hand put the laptop into low power mode (decreases the CPU power and therefore lowers the heat generated and power used), then [enable Window Projection](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/use-a-second-laptop-as-an-extended-monitor-with-windows-10-wireless-displays) (like Apple's Macbook Sidecar for iPads). Now the machine projecting to the laptop has an extended screen.